# Is it possible to search in the gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there something which can be used to search and highlight terms in terminal output? I need to search for "Error" after running `make`.

Comment: realized that there is a find option.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/670846/highlight-search-results-in-gnome-terminal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Using grep and its variations

Usually `grep` is used for plain searching. It would work like this:

```
make 2&>1 | grep Error
```

Or if there was a lot of output and you wanted to use a pager:

```
make 2>&1 | grep Error | less
```

However, if you want to see all the content, and not just the lines that match your search, you could install the `ack-grep` package, and then do this:

```
make 2>&1 | ack-grep --passthru Error
```

And if that generates a lot of output and you want to use a pager, you need a bit more syntax to preserve the color:

```
make 2>&1 | ack-grep --passthru Error --color | less -R
```

In all the examples I included `2>&1` which merges the STDERR and STDOUT output streams. Otherwise, you would only get STDOUT, which might not include all the errors.

One more variation is just to go straight into a pager and search within that:

```
make 2>&1 | less
```

One way to search in less is by typing `/` to enter a search term. See `man less` for more searching options.

### Using terminal menu

Using the Search menu or a keyboard short-cut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 22):

Go to the **search** menu. Otherwise:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>