# Highlight search results in GNOME Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way/plugin to highlight the searched strings in GNOME Terminal on Ubuntu (When using Ctrl+F or similar keys)? Not just a single result, but all which appear inside the window?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: How would the strings have been searched? Through the terminal's GUI? Using a tool like `grep`? Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail.

Comment: If you use grep for your search use the options --color=auto to get resuts highlighted. But I think it's default in Ubuntu anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I have replaced the default gnome terminal by Konsole from KDE. The price to pay is the substantial increase of size in your installation due to KDE libraries. This terminal offers to highlight the search results and opens the "Find" dialog as a bottom panel attached to the terminal which avoids annoying overlapping windows.